# I want to bake emission map from high poly to low poly

Tags: lighting, texture-baking, emission

I have a high poly mesh that some part of it has emission. In cycles render view I get a pretty good result with indirect light and bloom effect. What I wanna do is bake that light information into my low poly model. As my understanding bloom effect is post proccess so it doesn’t bake. Can I somehow imitate this effect on my lowpolys emission map?

What I want:

[image]

What I get:

[image]

Comment: You can bake the emission color, as you have done; if you want to bake a strength, you may need to scale (vector math) the color instead of using emission strength and bake to a floating point format image, like .exr.  However, the bloom itself is part of the rendering engine, and no, that full effect doesn't get baked-- it gets made from the emission in Blender or in your desired rendering engine.